# How to attach to and debug an ASP.NET MVC application running in Windows Azure Emulator?

Tags: debugging, iis, azure

I am writing an MVC 3 application to run in Windows Azure. On my local machine I use the Windows Azure emulator.

If I press F5 in my solution ("Start debugging") I'm able to put breakpoints and step through the code of my application.

Do you know if it's possible to attach to the application if it's already running (if it's been started with CTRL + F5, "Start without debugging")? If yes, how?

In ASP.NET running in IIS I just have to attach to the w3wp.exe process. How to do the same for the Windows Azure emulator?

Comment: I always run my webapps using the development server for debugging - not the Azure emulator. Why not just use the dev/IIS server? Is there an Azure-hosting specific issue?

Comment: @SliverNinja, good point, I could do that. I gave preference to the emulator because if there's a feature specific to Azure I'll have support for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the application in IIS (have a Sites section in your config file) then you will do it the same way with the emulator.  Azure creates an Application Pool for the deployment so you will just need to attach to that w3wp.exe process.